# How do I get javascript date object without time part

Tags: angular, timezone, momentjs, utc, moment-timezone

My client and server are at different time-zones.I am trying to get **datetime** in **javascript** but moment function or method `toISOString()` gives me string output. Even when I recreate the date object it again goes to **GMT time**. So how can I get date object without timezone issue?

Some lines from my code are as below. All return string and my `ngModel` is **Date** type.

```java
this.Element.nativeElement.value = this.Element.nativeElement.value.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Date objects in JavaScript contain both date, time and timezone. You have to convert it to something else, and you're using `toISOString()` for an ISO formatted valued.

If you only want a date value, then you can try using `toLocaleDateString()` which takes additional options depending upon what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
const str = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US')
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect.  `Date` objects in JavaScript only contain a UTC-based timestamp - which is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  In other words, the value returned by `.valueOf()` or `.getTime()`.  Everything else it does is computed to/from that.